# INVALID_PORT Error from firewall-cmd

Tags: firewall, firewalld, port

When I try to add a port via

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=XXXXX/tcp
```

I get the error

```
Error: INVALID_PORT: XXXXX
```

Why?

Comment: ports are numbers, XXXXX is not a number

Comment: I just using the Xs as a placeholder. The real number is something 12345 -- for example

Comment: port numbers are limited to 0-65535 ... so, the real number IS 12345? or something like 12345?

Comment: What's secret about a port number? Just use the actual number, and avoid the guessing for us.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a short research in the [code of firewalld/firewalld](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/search?q=INVALID_PORT) for `INVALID_PORT` and it seems you will get such an error

- when the port is not a number, in example `XXXXX`
- when the port number is out of range, in example `65536`
- when the syntax of the range is not using `-`, but in example `:`
- when the protocol is missing or invalid, in example `tcp`
- when the separator between port and protocol is not `/`

most likely in case of syntax errors.